# Whats wrong with this VHDL code

Tags: vhdl

I have this VHDL code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity addDecoder is
port(addrInput : in real; 
  ROM_sel_n, RAM_sel_n, PIO_sel_n, SIO_sel_n, INT_sel_n : out bit);
end addDecoder;

architecture Behavioral of addDecoder is

begin
AddSelect : process(addrInput) is
begin   
    if(addrInput <= X'3FFF') then
        ROM_sel_n <= '1';
    elsif(addrInput > X'3FFF' and addrInput <= X'5FFF') then
        RAM_sel_n <= '1';
    elsif(addrInput > X'5FFF' and addrInput <= X'8FFF') then
        PIO_sel_n <= '1';
    elsif(addrInput > X'8FFF' and addrInput <= X'9FFF') then
        SIO_sel_n <= '1';
    elsif(addrInput > X'9FFF' and addrInput <= X'FFFF') then
        INT_sel_n <= '1';
end process AddSelect;
end Behavioral;
```

What is wrong with it. I'm getting an error with the comparing of the hexadecimal values. Am I not doing this correctly? The error is this: parse error, unexpected INTEGER_LITERAL, expecting OPENPAR or IDENTIFIER

Comment: Check the data type of addrInput; I suspect that you intend std_logic_vector, not real. Also, address decoding is implemented more efficiently by masking bits, not integer comparison.

Comment: Thanks I will look into masking bits.

Comment: @Ian : Address decoding using integer comparisons will result in just the same as bit masking (assuming you have an address map which can be efficiently done with bit masking already) - the synthesiser will do the Right Thing.  I prefer it as it makes the addresses clearer in the code, rather than having to interpret the masks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Philippe already said, don't use std_logic_arith/unsigned.  Use `numeric_std`. [I've written about why...](http://parallelpoints.com/node/3).

If you want to continue to make comparisons with vectors (as well as using `"` rather than `'` around the values) you should make your `addrInput` an `unsigned` vector.

```
if addrInput < X"1FFF" then
```

Alternatively make it a `natural` and compare against integer values:

```
if addrInput < 8191 then
```

Also, as you are using `elsif`, you could simplify your statements thus:

```
if addrInput <= X"3FFF" then
    ROM_sel_n <= '1';
elsif addrInput <= X"5FFF" then
    RAM_sel_n <= '1';
-- etc
```

Finally, drop the `()`s around your `if` conditions, it makes you look like a C-programmer :)

Comment: Thanks all very helpful remarks. And yes I come from C programming language background.

Answer (score 4):

Several syntax errors.

Bit String literals should be written in double quotes: `X"0000"`, not single quotes `X'0000'`.

You forgot to close the if statement: `end if;`

Also, I recommend that you'd `use ieee.numeric_std.all;` instead of the non-standard libraries STD_LOGIC_ARITH and STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.